# Truncating text inside nested flex elements

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a nested flex container whose text I want to truncate when it isn't wide enough to show (https://codepen.io/BigMike/pen/mmMxQN).

**What I want**

(Large Screen)
[image: Large Screen]

(Small Screen with truncation)
[image: Small Screen]

I thought I could do it with

```
.truncated {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

but as I shrink the screen, the child reaches a point where it won't get any smaller.
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, if you add this rule, it will all stay on one line

```
.regular {
  flex-shrink: 0;      /*  won't allow element to become smaller than its content */
}
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWePgO)

```css
.rows {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 0px;
}
.nested-row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: white;
}

.nested-child {
  border: solid white 1px;
}

.truncated {
  overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
  border: solid white 1px;
  min-width: 0;
}

.regular {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="rows">
  <div class="child">
    <div class='nested-row'>
      <div class="nested-child truncated">
        I want this text to truncate but it breaks on a small screen
      </div>
      <div class='nested-child regular'>
        Now this doesn't wrap
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Some other content
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Some other content
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Some other content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! It looks like you forked the codepen when it was a little different from the original. So I'd just like to add that adding min-width: 0px to .child is also very important. Without this the div won't be able to shrink any smaller than the length of the truncated text div since it has whitespace: nowrap

Comment: @MichaelParton Great. Since the mentioned `.child` and `.truncated` classes already have `min-width`, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: It's my bad, the original pen didn't have that and I accidentally changed it after posting the question. I reverted it back so the question still makes sense.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is the white space property. You can just edit your style sheet like so.

```
.truncated {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: wrap;
}
```

Comment: That would wrap instead of truncating. I need everything on one line

Comment: it wouldn't be possible if you want that entire sentence on one line because as your shrink the container is basically pushing against the text and if it doesn't fit the new width by default it'd go to the next line word wise. You can try using `word-wrap: break-word;` instead, but I don't think it's possible.